# How to make sure a script runs once and only once

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, jquery-events, mako

I am writing a widget template, which will be included in a page where it is installed.

One may install several of the same kind of widget in one page, so my template may get included several times.

Now I have written some `JavaScript` to initialize the widget, you know, the clickings and hoverings.

My problem is that these `<script>`s get executed multiple times, for example, when I click something, the bounded function get executed several times.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
By the way, I am using the `Mako` template engine, and I've tried using the `c` variable to store a boolean flag, but it seems that the `c` get overridden every time.

Comment: online include the `<script>` tag once ?! or set a flag to check when its been run and dont run it if the flag has been set (cookie / global var)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678628/javascript-run-once-without-booleans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a similar solution to the one that's been used in C to prevent header-files to be included multiple times?

For example in the file "example.html" you could wrap your code in an if-statement like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    if (!window._EXAMPLE_HTML_) {
        window._EXAMPLE_HTML_ = true;
        // your code goes here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know how to share a variable between `included templates` with my template engine :(

Comment: @Satoru.Logic a global variable belongs to the browser not the script - so its available everywhere

Comment: BTW: It's not the best style to add _EXAMPLE_HTML_ to the window object. Better create another global object somewhere and use this.

Comment: What scope does the global object live in if not `window`?

Comment: Sure, it's a property of window, so the example is ok if you only need one variable. However, it would be a bit cleaner to use something like `window._INCLUDES_.EXAMPLEONE_HTML` and `window._INCLUDES_.EXAMPLETWO_HTML` if you need more than one, since this won't pollute the global scope with more variable names than necessary...